# Get all image src values from website using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, wordpress, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a wordpress site that has thousands of image files. Problem is, vast majority are redundant and just using up disk space. I need a way to know which ones are actually referenced by the html so that I can delete those that aren't.

Maybe Selenium WebDiriver could help? I could scrape the website to get the value of src attributes of all img elements.

Using the following code, the images collection is populated with 22 items - which is correct for the particular page. Problem is, I don't know how to get to the value of the "src" attribute?

```
var images = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(image.Text);
        }
```

Comment: You can use `image.GetAttribute("src")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAttribute` with `src` will get all the image url/path.

```
var images = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(image.GetAttribute("src"));
        }
```

Comment: Why post same answer?

Comment: Sorry. I thought it would make sense if i post the answer with user's sample code.Some users expects answers with their code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetAttribute` to get an attribute you need, example:

```
image.GetAttribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Html Agility Pack (HAP) after getting from selenium.